# Meaning of the symbol  in server.js for full stack apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Does somebody know what does the symbol  means in server.js for full stack (javascript) apps?.

for example :

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(` ==> Server now on port ${PORT}!`)});
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Hello world`?? Well, it's just a string, your imagination is the only limit :)

Comment: Could mean "production" mode is on...

Comment: That's the planet Earth. Often referred to as the "world".

Comment: More information on that character: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F30E

Comment: something having to do with the Illuminati most likely

Answer (score 2):

It's just another unicode character like any other character you type (in this case, the character translates to an Earth emoji).

Whoever wrote that example is just logging that "the server is now accessible to the world wide web through the port number."

Just try running the code. It'll appear in your console.